# .NET 4.0 EDMX Generate DB from model and then Execute SQL removes the DATA from Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm newbie with .NET Entity Framework 4.0 I'm using VS2010 and I created the EDMX file and then added my Entities in this model. After I've finished my Datamodel and set the Asscociation, I right click on and choose Generate DB from model.

Then it creates SQL scripts *.sql then I open the SQL and right click on Execute SQL Statements... What happens is all my tables are re-created...

ISSUE: All my test data in MasterData Tables are removed/deleted. I need to add the data back again manually...

I googled on "keep data generated Data model EDMX" etc. but couldn't find... Can someone advice me how I can avoid this problem?

Because I've e..g 15 MasterDataTable + other tables linked with these and I need to re-add the records back manually for all these tables... and 9 of 10 case I don't touch those tables in UI.

please advice how I can avoid this situation.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the model from the database (the reverse way you are taking now):

Double click the .edmx file to open the designer. In the middle of the designer, right click to show the contextual menu and click "update model from database". It will prompt a screen, check the DB parameters and click next. Now, you're in a sreen with TABS. The first tab is for adding tables as entities to the model. The second tab will its for update the model. Select the tables and views you need to add/update and click next. That's all.

Comment: So that means when there is (test) data in my Database I may not do generate database from model anymore, that also means all changes should be done in Database self (SSMS) and not in Conceptmodel anymore. right? In otherwords: As long you don't care the data you can use Conceptmodel changes (EDMX UI). As soon as you have data, even test data you want to keep, you may not use generate DB fro model. right? Btw the solution it works but I don't see the tables that I can select... in ADD/Refresh/Delete tabs....  but it works.

Comment: thanks...simple but you need to know it :). I prefered that I could always use the conceptmodel without going to the DB directoly for all changes with option (keep data).

Comment: It may take some seconds to retrieve the information to show the tables to add. Also.. If all the tables in the Database are already in the model, no tables will be shown to add. In the update Tab all tables showld be shown.  If my solution works, please accept it as solution :D Thanks!

Comment: ok. got it... they are sync. that's the reason why it did not show up.. thanks.